# Animate moving an image in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, api, canvas

Im new to using canvas but wonder if i could get some help or advice on where to start with this. i currently have a circle drawn on canvas and have tried multiple ways i thought might work but cant get my head round it. When searching online i can only really find help where the shapes are drawn in canvas itself.

Here is what i have so far: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexvolley/8eLL7L5L/)

JavaScript:

```
var one = document.getElementById("canvOne");
var canvOne = one.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    canvOne.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
};

img.src = "img/circle.jpg";

function oneStart(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++){
        img.style.left = i + 'px';
        setTimeout(oneStart, 1000);
    }
};
```

can anyone give me a hand with this please?

Comment: have you checked any examples? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/notearsgame/

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve? A canvas animation or a CSS animation?

Comment: i am trying to achieve a canvas animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8eLL7L5L/3/

javascript

```
//canvas one
var one = document.getElementById("canvOne");
var canvOne = one.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();

var animate = false;
var circlePosX = 10;
var circlePosY = 10;

img.onload = function () {
    canvOne.drawImage(img, circlePosX, circlePosY);
};

img.src = "http://www.alexvolley.co.uk/other/circle.jpg";

var start = function()
{
    animate = true;
}

var stop = function()
{
    animate = false;   
}

setInterval(function () {
    // Only update circle position if animate is true
    if (animate) {
        circlePosX += 1;
        canvOne.fillStyle = "#FFF";
        canvOne.fillRect(0, 0, one.width, one.height);
        canvOne.drawImage(img, circlePosX, circlePosY);
    }
}, 3);
```

All I have done is created 3 variables and added a few little functions, the circle's XPos and YPos are now stored so we can access them, I have also created a `bool` variable `animate` which is used to check if we should animate the circle.

The start function simply sets `animate` to true

The stop function simple sets `animate` to false

the setInterval just keeps running the same code over and over every 3 miliseconds, all this does is clears the canvas and then redraws the circle. If we don't clear the canvas you would see multiple circles appear when animate is true.

I hope this helped